# How to enable passive mode in putty psftp

Tags: putty

i need to enable passive mode in putty psftp in order to get a list of remote available files. HOw can I do that? Is there another wayt o do it using putty psftp

Comment: What errors are you seeing? Why do you believe you need to enable "_passive mode_"?

Answer (score 2):

[SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) is file transfer over SSH... there is no such thing as "*passive mode*" - this is an [FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) concept.

Comment: guess you are not answering my question. I am talking about PSFTP not just SFTP.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand... ["_PSFTP, the PuTTY SFTP client_"](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.52/htmldoc/Chapter6.html) - It's the same protocol...